# How can I display my product variations separately in the shopping cart template? Issues writing my Django add_to_cart view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, e-commerce

I will start off by saying I am very new to this and I am probably struggling because I did not get the basics right.

So I am trying to build an online shop with Django with a few products and each of the products is meant to have 2-5 variations. I added the products (and variations) manually in the admin panel.

I want the shopping bag table to display product variations separately such as:

1. Product X - Variation 1 - Quantity 2 - Price: 20 Euro - Total: 40 Euro
2. Product X - Variation 2 - Quantity 5 - Price: 30 Euro - Total: 150 Euro
3. Product Y - ....... etc.

This is my product model:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_friendly_name(self):
        return self.friendly_name


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Variation(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I realise I have price in both. Should I removed it in the product model when I want each of the variations to have a different price?

Okay so this is my cart view:

```
def add_to_bag(request, item_id):
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    variation = request.POST.get('variation')

    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    if 'variation' in request.POST:
        variation = request.POST['variation']
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    if variation:
        if item_id in list(bag.keys()):
            if variation:
                bag[item_id]['variation_dict'][variation] += quantity
            else:
                bag[item_id]['variation_dict'][variation] = quantity
        else:
            bag[item_id] = {'variation_dict': {variation: quantity}}
    else:

        if item_id in list(bag.keys()):
            bag[item_id] += quantity
        else:
            bag[item_id] = quantity

    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return render(request, 'bag/bag.html')
```

I also have this context:

```
def bag_contents(request):

    bag_items = []
    total = 0
    product_count = 0
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    for item_id, item_data in bag.items():
        if isinstance(item_data, str):
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=item_id)
            total += item_data * product.price
            product_count += item_data
            bag_items.append({
                'item_id': item_id,
                'quantity': item_data,
                'product': product,
            })
        else:
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=item_id)
            for variation, quantity in item_data['variation_dict'].items():
                total += quantity * product.price
                product_count += quantity
                bag_items.append({
                    'item_id': item_id,
                    'quantity': item_data,
                    'product': product,
                    'variation': variation,
                })

    grand_total = total
    context = {
        'bag_items': bag_items,
        'total': total,
        'product_count': product_count,
        'grand_total': grand_total,
    }

    return context
```

I want the code to check whether the item is in the bag_dictionary, if yes if the exact variation is in the bag and if yes to up the quantity by one.
If the item is in the bag but with a different variation id like to add this item separately with the quantity it was selected.
If its not there at all i want to create the bag_dictionary.

If I add the first variation its alright but at the second one I get a key error.

My questions now: Is my model the issue? How can I make this view right? Can I achieve what I want?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I am a little confused when reading your explanation. Is the bag a shopping cart? If so, are you trying to add different product to the cart, if a product with variation A already exists, add the quantity, if not, create a new key and value in dictionary?

Comment: If it is a just a Key Error, you are trying to access a key in bag dictionary that does not exist, it should have nothing to do with your models, but I would suggest to highlight the specific part of your code that it is causing the error and comment your code so others won't need to decode and guess what your code is trying to do. You will receive more help this way ;)